# Rich Edit Delphi Controls that Support RegEx Searches

Tags: delphi

I would greatly appreciate some help on anyone that has experience in working with Rich Edit controls in Delphi that support Regular Expression searches.

I've toyed around with RichEdit.dll V3 based controls only to find that MS's ITextSelection.FindText [implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787783(VS.85).aspx) uses some MS Mickey Mouse variant of regular expressions (i.e. ^p for paragraph) and so on.

Regular expression searches against TRichEdit1.text return mismatched SelStart locations due to hidden RTF formatting.

I guess this rules out any RichEdit.dll based controls/components unless someone could suggest a workaround?

I've also had a look at [Dream Rich Editor](http://www.dreamcompany.com/richeditor.html) but am worried that this is longer maintained (as of 2005). Otherwise, this looks ideal but cannot find any contact information to ask what ReGex syntax is supported (i.e. PCRE?)

Another option was [ProfHTMLEdit](http://www.profgrid.com/dhtmledit.html) but that chocked on the 2MB HTML file I tested it against. Editing was also non responsive on large files. Shame, as the control looked promising.

Yet another component was [TRichView](http://www.trichview.com/resources/actions/) but sadly that does not appear to support searching using Regular Expressions.

Simply put, my requirement is a Delphi 7 control that allow simple editing (i.e. bold, italic, selection alignments) and most importantly, the ability the search using Regular Expressions (preferably PCRE.. but not necessarily). Not too fussed what the underlying storage mechanism (rtf, html, xyz) is.

Any help or pointers/hints/tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "support regular expression searches"? Why and how should the control support it?
I mean you could take the text from a rich edit or any other control and search it using a regular expression library. To display the search dialog, use TFindDialog or write your own. To indicate a matched substring, set the selection in the control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html) may help.  I can't speak from experience with the components mentioned there, but as a HelpScribble user of many years I can say that Jan Goyvaert's support for his products is consistently outstanding.  You might try contacting him - he may know of a useful component.  It does occur to me that if you copied the text from a RichEdit control to a string variable (without formatting), you may be able to search that then map that position back to the text in your control.  Just a thought.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer.

"you may be able to search that then map that position back to the text in your control. Just a thought."

I did indeed try doing a regex search on the plain text but match positions on the plain text token matches don't map back when using RichEdit.SelStart ... sadly as life would have been much much simpler :)

Comment: Unfortunately, Jan Goyvaerts does not know of any rich edit Delphi components with built-in regex features.  Copying the plain text into TPerlRegEx and using the returned offsets and lengths to tell the rich edit control to make the selection and/or replacement should work.

Answer (score 2):

It's strange, but most lists of regexp components for Delphi don't mention the one I use almost all of the time:

```
VBScript_RegExp_55_TLB.pas
```

gotten by importing the "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" type library. It's gotten the VBScript label because it was introduced with VBScript/Javascript 5.5 together with Internet Explorer 5.5, which means you're sure end-user client have the library if you require users to have IE5.5 or above. I haven't combined it with a rich-edit control though.

Answer (score 1):

I use TRichView, and although as you say it does not support searching using Regular Expressions, you get it with full source code.

I've made various customizations to the package for my own software, and to change the internals of the search functionality to support Regular Expressions would not be too difficult in my estimation.

That is probably true of any RichEdit control where you have the source code.

So then take a look at: ["...use Regular Expressions in Delphi?"](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=1478) for an idea on how to add it yourself.

---

And I did find a user of TRichView who did implement regex. [He describes a bit of how he did it](http://www.trichview.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=732&highlight=regex), and the package he used was TRegEx. I am not familiar with TRegEx myself, but maybe he's referring [to this one](http://www.uptime.it/delphi/old/delphiregex.html), or you could try using [TRegExpr](http://regexpstudio.com/TRegExpr/TRegExpr.html).

You can find a good list of RegEx libraries for Delphi on About.com.

Comment: Thanks for the comments lkessler. I'll drop the TRichView developers an email along these lines. I did a search on their support forums, but did not see much traffic regarding regex support.

Cheers.

Comment: Awsome! I have used TRegExpr before but its not as good as TPerlRegEx. Thanks for the forum link! I've dropped the developers and email and will checkout the forum link you sent. Awsome * 2!

Comment: I have used TRegExpr before but its not as good as TPerlRegEx but should be able to use the same logic and easily replace one component for another.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some more research on TRichEdit and RichEd20.dll based on the excellent feedback to this question.

Some background. I want to use TPerlRegEx to search a TRichEdit control contents and highlight matched results. Previous attempts using RichEdit1.Lines.Text as the search subject resulted in a mismatched RegEx MatchedExpressionOffset and RichEdit1.SelStart.

I had thought that this was due to RTF formatting.. but that was just me having a brain fart!

On closer examination, there are two issue that need to be taken into consideration when not using RichEdit.FindText:

1. If using RichEdit.Text or RichEdit.Lines.Text then be aware that these contain extra #$D and #$A carriage return and line feed characters.
2. If using TPerlRegex.MatchedExpressionOffset then this is one based whilst TRichEdit.SelStart is zero based.

To correctly find the SelStart using TPerlRegex carriage returns and line feeds need to be taken into consideration when determining the SelStart.

Comment: When using Delphi 2009 and later, you also need to take into account that TPerlRegEx works with UTF8String, and the offsets are UTF-8 byte lengths.  The reason for that is that the underlying PCRE library uses UTF-8.